# Двойная проверка в @yield в Blade-шаблонах Laravel

Tags: laravel, php7, blade, laravel-8

Как известно, что конструкция `@yield` может принимать два аргумента - название секции и значение по умолчанию, если в шаблоне, который наследует - секция не определена.

Мне же нужно смочь как-то реализовать более расширенный функционал, что-то в виде:

```
<meta property="og:description" 
      content="@yield('og-description','description', 'Default')" />
```

Т.е. если секция *og-description* определена - выводится она, если нет - проверяется секция *description*, и если она определена выводится она. В противном случае выводится значение по умолчанию `Default`.

Голову ломал и придумал вот какой "костыль":

```
<meta property="og:description" 
      content="@include('chunks.chunk-description')" />
```

Содержимое файла *resources/views/chunks/description-chunk.blade.php*:

```
@php
$has_ogdescription = 0;
@endphp

@hasSection('og-description')
@php
$has_ogdescription = 1;
@endphp
@endif

@hasSection('description')
@php
if ($has_ogdescription != 1) $has_ogdescription = 2;
@endphp
@endif

@if ($has_ogdescription == 1)
@yield('og-description')
@else
@yield('description','Default')
@endif
```

В принципе вопрос решен. Но решение мне очень-очень не нравится! Хотелось бы что-то более изящное.

**Вопрос: как такое сделать более компактно, более функционально?**

И попутно еще два мелких смежных вопроса:

1. Как в @php-блоке вызвать что-то типа @hasSection('название секции')?
2. Как в @php-блоке получить содержимое @section('название секции')?

Answer (score -1):

{{ 'og-description' ?? 'description' }}

По поводу секций, у Вас нарушена логика приложения.

```
@if ($has_ogdescription == 1)
@yield('og-description')
@else
@yield('description','Default')
@endif
```

Особенно здесь.

Comment: Да нет, тут все у меня норм - могу весь код прокомментировать. Да и выполняется он на тестах на 100% правильно.

Comment: Вы явно не слышали о шаблонах проектирования (FrontController & ApplicationController). Все обработчики должны выполняться в Сервисах или Моделях, такова логика MVC, пересмотрите свой код еще раз и вынесите логику в классы где ей место...

Comment: Если не трудно - прошу ваш "совет" детально описать в вашем ответе. Благо решается вопрос только о двух сущностях "description" и "og-description".  Уверен, у вас получится лаконично.